# Передача данных между потоками asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Каким образом можно передавать данные между потоками `asyncio`? Можно создать глобальную переменную. Есть ли аналог golang каналов?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html чем не устраивает? Если асинк зависит от GIL тогда можно и просто через переменную. GIL все обещают вот вот убить, но когда это будет и будет ли от этого лучше это еще вопрос.

Comment: @Yakov ага. Я через переменную всегда делал. Но тут вопрос встал про гошные каналы и я решил уточнить, как дела в питоне. Спасибо

Comment: По сути что поток что корутина в асинкио все-равно работают на одном ядре. если у вас много ввода вывода то асинк ио вам в помощь. если у вас много вычислений и мало ввода / вывода, то асинк ио и потоки у вас будут медленно работать, тогда надо мультипроцессы, а они умеют обмениваться только через пайпы/очереди, там глобальные переменные не прокатят. в общем реальной многопоточности в одном процессе питона пока нет, она кооперативная, из-за GIL. не знаю может в 3.9 что-то изменилось. но в 3,5 3,6, 3,7 точно реальной многопоточности не было.

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "потоками asyncio" в данном случае? Таски?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yakov - хоть питон и одномоментно работает в одном ядре - это ядро может меняться, а данные могут остаться в кеше другого ядра. Да и GIL блокирует только функции реализованные на питоне. Сишный вызов (Ввод-Вывод - как частный случай) может работать паралельно.

Передача через переменную совсем не безопасна в нагруженной системе. Чтоб обратиться к глобальной переменной нужно поставить блокировку [через лок или кондишн](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html).

[Очереди](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) идеальный вариант передачи из одного потока в другой, если передаем последовательности.

Comment: Если эта переменная не используется в вызовах библиотек на си, а в нее результат копируется из другой локальной, то, вероятно это будет безопасно, если переменная передается куда-то в код на си, может и нужно. приведите пример кода на питоне где проблема воспроизводима? я не часто пишу на питоне, может я и не прав. но как я понимаю, в один момент времени одномоментно работает всегда один поток, и его переключение идет последовательно, в случае с asyncio вообще понятие потока не совсем истина, это просто кооперативная многозадачность аля виндоуз 95, какое другое ядро, если поток один?

Comment: Как можно убедиться что она не используется в друглм треде кроме как ввставлением блокировки? Gil тормознет тред в 99.9999 % случаев, но программы должны быть надежными

Comment: @Yakov например в одном треде ты делаешь сортировку списка, а в другом забираешь через pop элемент оттуда.

Comment: еще раз не понимаю, как это соотносится с асинкио? речь про них-же была в комментариях и в вопросе. асинкио это не много потоков это один поток с эмуляцией многопоточности. там неоткуда взяться рейс кондишинам в принципе в виду дизайна. По крайней мере до питона >3.8 с множественными интерпретаторами. С чего вы взяли, что планировщик захочет этот один поток перенести на другое ядро и кэши оставить на старом? Если это произошло, то это явно не вина скрипта, это баг интерпретатора.

Comment: @Yakov тред пул эккзекутор, есть способы запустить  асинкио в потоках. Я думаю автор знает о потоках и конкуреном выполнении и задает вопрос о потоках

Comment: Ну если у вас не раздельные процессы какой в этом будет смысл? (я про запуск нескольких очередей для asyncio?). Насколько я понимаю от GIL досихпор не отказались именно по причине того, что с ним легко и безопасно можно интегрировать с питом не потокобезопасную библиотеку на си с минимумом усилий/правок. использование примитивов синхронизации / мьютексов может повлиять на скорость исполнения других скриптов, особенно однопоточных, т.к. вызывает инвалидацию кеша, генерит ненужные прерывания, которые отвлекают другие ядра от выполнения кода, что сказывается на конечной скорости исполнения.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115345/discussion-between-yakov-and-eri).